# mediaelementjs player's button disappeared?

Tags: mediaelement.js

mediaelementjs player was working okay on my wordpress (P2 theme) and then I upgraded the theme, the player still works but all the buttons have disappeared.

I uploaded and reverted back to the original theme, the problems remains. I have no clue why the buttons are not showing up anymore ? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue and it turned out to be a lack of MIME support in my Apache configuration.  The control button images for mediaelementjs are SVG files, and not all Apache installations have a mime definition for that filetype.

Solution on my server was to edit /etc/mime.types and add the line:

```
image/svg+xml svg svgz
```

Then I restarted Apache and everything worked fine.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check your CSS for the following style being applied to buttons...

```
button {
width: auto !important;
}
```

That one rule was responsible for the missing mediaelement.js controls in my case (for me this only happened in Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

Check the inspector and make sure that your paths are correct. I had a similar problem and found that the CSS didn't have the correct image path (e.g. img/img_name.png).